# Programatically join a set of images together to form a background

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, background

Does anyone know of a way to create a repeating background formed from a set of images similar to what you see in the Zune player. The images would be of different sizes, so there would have to be a way for them to be stitched together.

Here is an example of what I am looking for, except that some of my images may be rectangular rather than square. [image: Zune background]

The background is for a WPF app.

Comment: Suppose you have two images A and B as in http://i.imgur.com/BrFbv.png. What is your plan to arrange A and B since they cannot fill a rectangular space ? Also, looking quickly into the image you posted, I see no repetition in there. What do you mean by "repeating background" then ?

Comment: Is there a library out there that can do this?

Comment: It is always important to know what you are actually trying to solve. What you have here is called bin packing, a NP-hard problem in several of its variations. Here is another illustration for you: http://i.imgur.com/e4h29.png. Your bounding rectangle is actually restricted only on two sides, the other two are relaxed. Now suppose you packed 3 images (in red) already. Next you want to pack an image at bottom that has a height smaller or equal than the current space used there. Suppose you have ordered your images somehow, and the first one you have now is called 'A'.

Comment: (continuing). This image 'A' does not fit in the space. But you happen to have another image 'B' that does, so you pick it. The same problem occurs for the next packing, and so on. If you happen to have large images, then you could downscale them as needed to fit (upscaling is mostly unwanted). Otherwise, you would end up with spaces between images, which is unwanted. After you fill this box of a certain minimum width x minimum height, pick the central part of it, render the images there and declare it as your background.

Comment: @mmgp I may end up with spaces as there will be 1 - n images available for a background. Seems like only square images would work. So when a user uploads an image I could accept square shapes and ask the user to select a square portion of a rectangular shape for use in the background. I may have to drop this idea and take a simpler approach like using a single image as a background with a filter over it.

Comment: If you can repeat images already used, then you can guarantee that there will be no space left. The problem now is that you want to keep a good visual, without using a lot of tiny resized images to fit the space.

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you have a repository of images. This would be the thought process of it.

1) create a class that holds the width, height, path and any other info you need to capture

2) create another class using the first one as the base class and include the x and y coords of where it was drawn

3) Create a list to hold the images

4) create a list to hold images that were drawn

3) create a bitmap of what ever size you want it to be

4) grab an image from the list and draw it at 0,0 of our bitmap and remove from the list(step 3) and add to list (step 2) with x and y coords

5) grab another image and ...here is where you want to decide how you are going to write your algorithm.

an example would be

Check the dimensions of the image and place it below the first image at 0, image_1,height and continue down until you reach the end of the bitmap.  Now its just puxzzle game to fit the images in by checking their dimensions and what dimension you need.. or work from the top down

Comment: and you really only need to create 1 class to hold all the info for the picture

Comment: Thank you. The tricky thing I see now will be joining together images of different dimensions. If they were square it would be much easier, then it would a matter of resizing the different squares.

Comment: I find this answer funny :) It is split into two parts: a trivial one and an impossible one. The impossible part was left as an exercise.